# How to find and get a string data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script. I get this script as a string through the database. I need a specific value in this script. How can I get this data out of string?

### The data(type=str) I extracted from the database

```
data = """if(description)
{
  script_name("name");
  script_summary("summary");
  script_version("version");
  script_tag(name:"base_vector", value:"AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C");
  exit(0);
}"""
```

### The data I want for each script

```
base_vector: AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C
```

This value is changing for each script.

Comment: this is not valid Python syntax

Comment: @AzatIbrakov No, it's a string OP is trying to find some substring in.

Comment: How much do you know about that string? Will the line always start with `script_tag`? Will it always be in the 6th line? What have you tried? Regular expressions should work fine.

Comment: Thank you far editing. @tobias_k. Data is a str and i find a spesific data in this str. I have 1000 data of these data in my hand, and not all in sixth line.

Comment: Okay, so what _do_ all those 1000 strings have in common? First you have to identify some kind of pattern, e.g. how the line starts, or the layout of the string you want to find itself, then you can translate that pattern into a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using **regular expressions** for that.

```
import re

rx = r'name\s*\:\s*\"(\w+)\"\s*\,\s*value\s*\:\s*\"(.*)\"'

text = """if(description)
{
  script_name("name");
  script_summary("summary");
  script_version("version");
  script_tag(name:"base_vector", value:"AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C");
  exit(0);
}"""

m = re.search(rx, text)
print(m.group(1) + ': ' + m.group(2))
```

The output is:

```
base_vector: AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C
```

You can enhance regular expression, but provided one will work on your input data.

Note lots of `\s*` tokens in expression - they allow using spaces in input data.

Answer (score 0):

here is half of it leaving rest to you

```
m = re.search('(?<=value:")..[A-Z|a-z|:|/]*', data)
print(m.group(0))
```

> 'AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C'

Read this whole document at some point of your life: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html